# Is there a way to get all relative URL paths to serve a single absolute page URL?

Tags: html, url, redirect

What I'm looking for is a way for all paths like `example.com/blog`, `example.com/about`, `example.com/burnt/toast`, etc. to all go straight to `example.com` and get the same `index.html` file, from which I can respond to the different URL paths with JavaScript.

Is this possible without adding a physical redirect placeholder file for each of the extensions? Without having to use node.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a "front controller."  It is usually implemented in `.htaccess` using a rewrite rule:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

That rule says: "except for files that actually exist, handle all URL paths with `index.html`."